# Not able to produce Histogram because of this error message

Tags: r, histogram

Basically I have the code as mentioned below.

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(gridExtra)
library(Matrix)


# The following four lines will read in a TXT/CSV file
# If R is installed on your PC, use dir <- "C:\\temp", dir <- "C:\\RApps", etc.   

dir <- "C:\\RApps"
setwd("C:\\RApps")
file <- "Yelp3.csv"
df <- read.csv(paste(dir, file, sep = "\"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$text <- sapply(df$text,function(row) iconv(row,to = 'UTF-8'))
df$text<- tolower(df$text)
RunBreenSentimentAnalysis = TRUE
if(RunBreenSentimentAnalysis == TRUE) {
        hu.liu.pos=scan('C:/RApps/positive-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';') #load +ve sentiment word list
        hu.liu.neg=scan('C:/RApps/negative-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';') #load -ve sentiment word list
        pos.words=c(hu.liu.pos) # can add terms here e.g. c(hu.liu.pos, 'newterm', 'newterm2')
        neg.words=c(hu.liu.neg)
    
        score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')
            {
            
            # we got a vector of sentences. plyr will handle a list or a vector as an "l" for us    
        # we want a simple array ("a") of scores back, so we use "l" + "a" + "ply" = "laply":    

            scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) 
                {
                word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+') # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package            
                words = unlist(word.list)  # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much             
                pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)        
                neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)             
                # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA. we just want a TRUE/FALSE:        
                pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)        
                neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)         
                # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():        
                score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)        
                return(score)   
            }, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress )     
    
            scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)    
            return(scores.df)
        }

        scores <- score.sentiment(df$text,pos.words, neg.words, .progress = 'text')
        hist.default(scores$score)
        ggplot(scores, aes(x=score)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1) + xlab("Sentiment score") + ylab("Frequency") + theme_bw()  + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 14)) + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size = 14, angle=90, vjust = -0.25)) + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,2,2), "cm")) # plots nice histogram
        ggsave(file = "OverallSentimentHistogram1.pdf") # export the plot to a PDF file

        # Extract documents by sentiment category neutral, positive, negative, very positive, and very negative 

            scores.neutral<-subset(scores,scores$score==0) # get documents with only neutral scores
            scores.pos<-subset(scores,scores$score>=1) # get documents with only positive scores
            scores.neg<-subset(scores,scores$score<=-1) # get documents with only negative scores
            scores.verypos<-subset(scores,scores$score>=2) # get documents with only very positive scores
            scores.veryneg<-subset(scores,scores$score<=-2) # get documents with only very negative scores
        # Export data
            write.csv(scores,file = "SentimentScores1.csv")
            write.csv(scores.neutral,file = "SentimentScores_Neutral1.csv")
            write.csv(scores.pos,file = "SentimentScores_Positive1.csv")
            write.csv(scores.neg,file = "SentimentScores_Negative1.csv")
            write.csv(scores.verypos,file = "SentimentScores_VeryPositive1.csv")
            write.csv(scores.veryneg,file = "SentimentScores_VeryNegative1.csv")

} "
```

The errors I'm getting are

1.

```
Read 2006 items
Read 4784 items
Error in df$text : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

2. 

```
# first clean the twitter messages by removing odd characters
> df$text <- sapply(df$text,function(row) iconv(row,to = 'UTF-8'))
Error in df$text : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> df$text<- tolower(df$text)
Error in df$text : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: Typically the `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` happens when you subset an object that doesn't exist, that has the same name as a function (`df()` is also a function).  Check to make sure that wherever your `df` is defined, it's working correctly and giving the output you're expecting (and that you ran that line).

Comment: Thanks! I am still a beginner in R. Will try it out and see what's exactly wrong.